# Wordpress - вывести посты с "метками" на главную

Tags: wordpress

Хочу на главной странице вывести n количество новостей из двух типов - популярные и новые. С таким условием что мне нужно самому выбирать какие посты отображать главной и с какой меткой. Вот яркий пример того чего я хочу добиться:

> http://themeforest.net/item/shoppica-premium-opencart-theme/full_screen_preview/235470

Как это лучше сделать ?

Видел на одном в одном шаблоне возле поста вот такое:
[image]

что это ? Может можно при помощи этих "меток" сгруппировать нужные посты и вывести в нужном месте ?

PS группировать по типу постов, категориям, Тегам не вариант.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проще всего использовать плагин.

[Посмотрите здесь](http://cms-wordpress.ru/wordpress-popular-posts-populyarnye-zapisi-wordpress/)

Comment: Это совсем не то что мне нужно, мне нужно самому выбирать какие посты размещать на главной и с какой меткой и не виджетом. Выше в посте я добавил пример.

Comment: Так можно сделать через custom fields:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields
А потом делать выборку в шаблоне:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts
Пример выборки:
$args = array(
 'meta_query' => array(
  array(
   'key' => 'featured',
   'value' => 'yes',
  )
 )
 );
$postslist = get_posts( $args );

В параметр meta_query передается массив с именем пользовательского поля и его нужным значением.

Еще можно почитать об всех возможностях работы с custom fileds:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters

Comment: Хотя можно создать дополнительные категории(например: Акции, Спецпредложения) и при добавлении или изменении товара, просто отмечать его категории и еще доп. категорию. А на странице вывода, сделать выборку по id доп. категории.

А то, что у Вас на скриншоте - называется пользовательские поля записи. О чем я писал выше. Для удобства использования, рекомендую использовать сторонний плагин, например: Advanced Custom Fields

Answer (score 2):

Вот поиск по тегам, подробно можно посмотреть в http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

```
<?
    $args = array('tag'=>'main','orderby'=>'date','order'=>'DESC')
    $loop = new WP_Query($args)    
    while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
?>
    <h3><a href="<?the_permalink()?>"><?the_title()?></a></h3>
<?endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```